# How to get the GraphQL schema in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have a `React` project that uses `TypeScript` and `GraphQL` using `apollo`.

I have a global Type file that has all the required files. It is generated from the `schema.json` file , by running `apollo-codegen`

The steps I follow are:

- Run the GraphiQL
- Copy the response of POST request to graphQL
- Paste it in the schema.json file
- Create the graphQL query ( `.graphql` file )
- Run `apollo-codegen`

Is there a better way to do this programatically ?

I'm not sure what part of the code to share along with this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [gql2ts](https://github.com/avantcredit/gql2ts) and then run `$ gql2ts schema.json`

Comment: In this case also, I'll have to create the schema.json file myself right?

Comment: Yes... you will need the `schema.json`.

Comment: You can check this [post](http://avant.engineering/graphql-and-typescript/)

Answer (score 1):

I have had great success with the following project: https://graphql-code-generator.com/

Works amazing across your graphql server and client implementation.